# Change preloaded content [AJAX]

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

My files:
`signup.php`, `form.php`, `success.php`, `failure.php`.

In `signup.php` there's an area `<div id="myarea"></div>`. Inside of this block I load the `form.php` by default via `<?php include ("form.php"); ?>`.

Now I want to show the `success.php` or `failure.php` whether the signup was successfull or not.

My Question: How can I replace the content/loaded file in `myarea`?
(Until now I did not wrote the file the data of the form is sent to.)

EDIT: I'm new to php and so on

Comment: You have the option to fetch with ajax after page load and change the page content with javascript after getting the result. Or you could load them dynamically with php and using `if/else` to determine the what to include.

Comment: Hey Simon - just following up. Was your question answered satisfactorily? If there is more we can help with, please add a comment below my answer, or edit your question to ask for more help. Otherwise, it would be great if you could choose a "best answer" (click the checkmark beside the answer) to close out the question. ***Also take a moment upvote (instead-of / in-addition-to) the checkmark, to reward answers that were also helpful - it costs you nothing but helps us*** If no answer was helpful, please post your own and select it with the checkmark to close out the question. *Thanks!*

Answer (score 3):

This is not using ES2017, but it is a simple example and will give you the general idea.

I assume you are using ajax to verify the login, so something like below.

When you come back from the ajax (that is, inside the ajax `.done()` or `.success` or whatever-you-use function, you can either use `$.load()` to load the new content and `$('#myarea').html()` to replace the content of the `#myarea` div, or even something as simple as `$('#someHiddenDiv').show()` to reveal a previously hidden div.

Here is a simplistic example:

```
var my_id = $('#loginid').val();
var my_pw = $('#loginpw').val();
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
     url: 'ajax/login.php',
    data: 'id=' +my_id+ '&pw=' +my_pw,
}).done(function(recd){
    if (recd==1) {
        var newhtml = $.load('success.php');
        $('#myarea').html(newhtml);
        //-OR-
        //$('#myhiddendiv').show();
    }else{
        $('#loginid').val('');
        $('#loginpw').val('');
        alert('Please try logging in again');
    }
});
```

---

Now that you see a very basic example, here is how we do it these days:

[How to do AJAX in 2018](https://medium.com/@mattburgess/how-to-get-data-with-javascript-in-2018-f30ba04ad0da)

[Understanding the Fetch API](https://flaviocopes.com/fetch-api/)

[Async/Await in 2017](https://getmesh.io/blog/make-ajax-requests-great-again/)